# Can't synonym tag even it exists in system

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-synonyms

I spotted for some redundant tags like [iphoneos](/questions/tagged/iphoneos) and [iphone-ios](/questions/tagged/iphone-ios) Check this image:

[image]

and tried to suggest synonym of there for `ios` but getting error,

> Failed to propose synonym:
>   The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym

Check this again:
[image]

Please correct me if I am dong something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iphoneos](/questions/tagged/iphoneos) is currently a synonym of [i-os](/questions/tagged/i-os), and therefore can't be added as a synonym to [ios](/questions/tagged/ios).

This is stupid and should be fixed.

Comment: Who in the world made *that* a synonym? They deserve a good smack.